# Can I upgrade multiple streets at the same time?

Tags: simcity-2013

In Simcity you can upgrade roads by pressing R during road building, but I'm stuck doing it one by one. Is it possible to select multiple streets and do them all together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today, upgrading multiple streets at the same time is impossible.

However, I have heard other people ask the same question, so there is a fighting chance that multiple street upgrades will be added in the future.